# Separating entities in the business logic layer

Tags: design, mvc

I am going to start a project, which in the `BLL` would have something like:

- Jumper
- Map
- Record

I need to keep track of all those, so I will make probably classes which hold them, e.g.:

- JumperList
- MapList
- RecordList

First of all, is that a good practice to hold all the objects and is it good if I separate them like:

`BLL.Entity` for the `Jumper`, `Map`, `Record`
and
`BLL.List` for `JumperList`, `MapList`, `RecordList`

---

Okay, I may have written it in a confusing way. What I meant was, is it good to make it like that:

```
BLL.Entity
 - Jumper
 - Map
 - Record
BLL.List
 - JumperList
 - MapList
 - RecordList
```

Comment: I don't really think you have enough entities to get any advantage from separating them. I don't even think you can think of sensible way to separate them.

Comment: @Euphoric I have more than 10 classes, those 3 I have given are just an example. My point was to separate the entity classes and entityList classes

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: What do the classes do?

Comment: @LynHeadley, they are in the BLL.. just basic objects which I will generate from XML

Answer (score -1):

Separating is often good practise. But i prefer Repository, not List. And also look at this separation:

```
Bll.Jumper
    +JumperEntity
    +JumperRepository
Bll.Map
    +MapEntity
    +MapRepository
Bll.Record
    +RecordEntity
    +RecordRepository
```

Comment: I was probably confusing, please check my additional example

Comment: For example, when updating in Jumper context you will probably want to look up both Repository and Entity. Or looking for projects domains, this is looking pretty clear. I think separating with item's domain better than item's task. Don't worry about Repository or List word.